# Having issues typing into my input box or clicking on things[React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a bit confused as why my input box is frozen and a click is not working on my label. I looked around for an answer and read one that said i needed to set the value and a callback. Did that and still no go. Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ItemsNew extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: 'a',
            price: '',
            location: '',
            used: '',
            descriptipn: '',
            imgUrl: '',
            shippingCost: ''
        }
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    handleOnChange = (event) => {
        debugger
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value 
        })
    }

    handleOnClick = (event) => {
        debugger
    }

    render(){
        return  (
            <div>
                <label onClick={this.handleOnClick}>name</label>
                <input id='name' type='text' onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.name}/><br/>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default ItemsNew;
```

My console.log hits and prints out this.state. However none of my event handler get hit with the debugger. The input box does get printed out with an 'a' when on the first load of the page.

Looking through the React dev tools this is my DOM.
![image of DOM]: https://ibb.co/mQEaN6
Also the tools say that the props are Read Only.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, maybe the problem is not in your code but in somewhere else.

Comment: Yea I built a simple react app without other dependencies and without routers and the input is not frozen. But as far my other app i have all kinds of things going on. Gotta dig deep now I guess.

Comment: So glad you asked this!  Helped me fix my code.  Also fixed it by increasing the zIndex of the parent element of the input tag. (Had to be the parent tag.  Increasing zIndex on the actual input tag didn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building my app back up from scratch I found the problem is in the CSS. Which I find strange. The rendered out div was nested in a main div that had the z-index style of -1 so that my header content was on top of it. I changed the z-index around for the header and gave the header a position of relative and now everything works.

Previous css code:

```
.main{
    width: 600px;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 7px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    box-shadow: 10px 13px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transform: translateY(-12%);
    overflow-y: auto;
    **z-index: -1;**
    background: lightblue;
}

.app-title{
    text-align: center;
    color: teal;
    margin-top: 38px;
}
```

New CSS code:

```
.main{
  width: 600px;
  height: 650px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  box-shadow: 10px 13px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transform: translateY(-12%);
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

.app-title{
  text-align: center;
  color: teal;
  margin-top: 38px;
  **position: relative;**
  **z-index: 1;**
}
```